# Celery on windows for video processing

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, gpu, que

How to implement celery on windows without any conflict between GPUs?

I want to implement celery on windows without any conflict between GPUs
How to connect that to Flask? Is it worth?
If our application has a long running task like processing some uploaded video..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Windows is not supported by Celery for quite some time...